# How to use single Database User Management (DBUM-12.2.1.3.0) connector for multiple Oracle Databases in single OIM environment

Tags: database, oracle, connector, oim

I've integrated DBUM connector with OIM 12c for "xyz" database as a target system. Now I'd like to integrate another "abc" database in the same environment. In such a case, what would be the ideal practice of integrating new database?
a. Should I repeat the same process as I did for xyz database?
b. Should I clone the existing DBUM connector?
c. Or crate new IT Resource with same IT Resource Type, and crate custom Resource Object, Lookup Definition, Process Definition and form.

Any input will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try creating a new IT resource and defining a new application instance?

I personally never messed with this connector, but as for other ones, they definitely would support that (11.x.x.x version of those)